# Simple Prism Bootstrapper

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

im currently porting my program to using Prism 6, it's a WPF application.
So i installed Prism.Unity (6.1.1) which came with Prism.Wpf (6.1.0), Prism.Core (6.1.0), Unity (4.0.1) and CommonServiceLocator (1.3.0).

Then i came along those PRISM samples, but for the love of god i can't get it to run.
Here's my Bootstrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : Prism.Unity.UnityBootstrapper
{
    /// <exception cref="ActivationException">If there are errors resolving the shell instance.</exception>
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();

        this.RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IWorkRepository), typeof(WorkRepository), true);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately i can't start it. VS 2015 says it needs System.Runtime to run

```
return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
```

but once added the whole class is marked as error. If i start it directly i get the exception it couldn't load Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.
I'm wondering of the dependency since several posts (including ms) suggests to remove all Practices.*.

Help would be really appreciated, since i can't get it to run. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `using`s do you use?

The whole bootstrapper can be as simple as this (created by the Prism-template):

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using Prism.Unity;
using PrismUnityApp2.Views;
using System.Windows;

namespace PrismUnityApp2
{
    class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell()
        {
            Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

and `System.Runtime` isn't needed as reference. Probably you inadvertently use a namespace from that (instead of `Microsoft.Practices.Unity` where the `Container.Resolve<>` extension is).

Comment: Ok, I ran the template and everything worked. But do i need those Microsoft.Practices.*.dlls? Other threads suggest deleting them.

Comment: Have a look at the `packages` folder in your solution - those are assemblies from Unity, and if you want to use it, you better reference its assemblies ;-) But I agree that the naming might be misleading, esp. if used right next to Prism that doesn't have `Microsoft.Practices` in its name anymore...